# Utilização do comando for em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funções, for, comandos

Galera, podem me ajudar ? Estou tentando fazer com que uma função seja executada e que me retorne a palavra "Azul" 4 vezes, através de um Ciclo. Tentei escrever isso aqui, mas deu o seguinte erro

> > > ReferenceError: imprimirAzul4 is not defined.

Esse é o código que escrevi:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  function imprimirAzul4 () {
    return "Azul";
  }
}
```

Alguém sabe me dizer onde esta errado?

Comment: O teu código e o teu erro não têm a ver um com o outro... ou seja creio que esse erro vem de outra versão de código e não aquele que está na pergunta... podes colocar o código completo que deu esse erro?

Comment: Estranho, o código é esse mesmo. segue: 
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  function imprimirAzul4 () {
    return "Azul";
  }
}


Erro :

solution.js:29
var __mumuki_query_result__ = imprimirAzul4 ();
^

ReferenceError: imprimirAzul4 is not defined

Comment: este erro é do console do mumuki, tem um monte de perguntas iguais deste mumuki em um curto periodo de tempo e desta função inclusive

Comment: Você tem certeza disso? Pq se for é muito sério. Essa plataforma tem uma parceria com uma escola de Programação, e estamos fazendo exercicios online que contabilizam pontos, numa espécie de vestibular. Quem tiver as melhores colocações é contemplado com um curso completo de progamação. Se a plafatorma está com problema, podem exigir recontagem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que declarar a função antes do for e chamá-la conforme código abaixo:

```
function imprimirAzul4() {
    return "Azul";
}

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    imprimirAzul4();
}
```

OU coloca o for dentro da função:

```
function imprimirAzul4() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        console.log("Azul");
    }
}

imprimirAzul4(); // chamada da função
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer igual o @Benilson respondeu declarar a função fora do looping, ou chamar a função logo após declarar, essa técnica é chamada de **self-executing function** que basicamente é função que é executada logo após ser declarada.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  (function imprimirAzul4() {
    console.log("Azul");
  })();
}
```